# "Definition" of the Real Numbers as a Subfield of the Complex Numbers

Tags: analysis

Consider the set $\{(a,0):a\in R\}$ with complex addition and multiplication, and a relation $<$ such that  if $x,y\in R$ and $x<y$, then $(x,0)<(y,0)$.

Is this complete ordered field the subset of C that we all treat just like R ?

Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts about this question?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly that subset of $C$ is uniquely isomorphic to $R$: any two complete ordered fields are isomorphic, and the isomorphism between them is unique.

Based on those mathematical facts, perhaps the psychological corollary that we all treat them as being just like each other is true. In general, though, treating isomorphic objects as being "the same" can sometimes get you in trouble, so one should make that psychological corollary with care.